# Update old program from old version or from scratch

Tags: c#, android, ios, pascal

I've been given the job of updating some old code written in Pascal, which was targeted to run on Windows.

My job is to rewrite the code to run on ios and Android. I've been given the source code, however the code is not well documented, difficult to understand (since I have never programmed in Pascal before) and it contains some very difficult maths.

I'll be programming in C#, however I'm not sure if I should try and decipher the given source code or start from scratch?

Answer (score 0):

I can appreciate your problem, but that is basically an impossible question to answer with the information given.  Basically, you have the choice of finding a well supported Pascal compiler for iOS & Android (Unix OSes supporting gnu languages could use this http://www.gnu-pascal.de/gpc/h-index.html, perhaps a port or something similar is available for iOS and Android) and learning Pascal ... or rewriting the code in C#/Mono.  You could also consider taking parts of the pascal code and creating libraries out of it and calling them from C#.  Perhaps a tools is available to convert Pascal to C# (and does it work).

Things to consider are:

- Timeline, how much time do you have to do this
- List item
- How easily can you    learn a new language (do you just know c# or a
  dozen other languages)
- Is it easier to treat this as a completely new project, by converting
  the Pascal to a specification.  This will give you greater freedom in structuring your C# without being "polluted" by the original design decisions (which may not longer be valid) of the existing code.

You might want to read through this thread: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/60a25852-8653-407a-97ac-438ee80d99a4/ms-pascal-to-cnet?forum=csharpgeneral

Comment: Gnu Pascal supports iOS and Android? Where did you get that?

Comment: Ok, bit if a mis-statement <blush>, I'll edit.  Unix OSes will generally support gnu compilers.

Comment: GNU Pascal is not in the main GCC distro, it is an add on and not actively maintained afaik. One cannot depend on it working on a recent (4.x) compiler without checking afaik. Read and weep: http://www.g-n-u.de/pipermail/gpc/2010-July/014700.html  note the date.

Answer (score 0):

In theory you could use the latest version of Delphi XE (object pascal) to compile to Native iOS and Android and not have to rewrite the Pascal at all.

Comment: Only Delphi XE5+ supports iOS and Android

Answer (score 0):

And also Free Pascal (http://www.freepascal.org) supports iOS and Android to some degree.

How practical it is depends on the level of investment in, and quality of the old code.

C# doesn't seem to be a good choice though, since it is not a native language on either platform. At least The main Pascal vendor (Embarcadero) supports these targets directly, contrary to MS.